# What is the difference between "withered" and " shrivelled"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, adjectives

Is There a kind of nuance between those two words? Can I use them interchangeably? Can I use them in other scenarios besides plants, roots, leaves? (e.g. His generosity has withered)

Comment: The words are very similar. Flowers and grass are generally described as *withered* and not *shriveled*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=withered+grass%2C+withered+flowers%2C+shriveled+grass%2C+shriveled+flowers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithered%20grass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithered%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshriveled%20grass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshriveled%20flowers%3B%2Cc0). I think this is because when things *shrivel*, they have to become smaller, while things that dry out but don't shrink can *wither*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the definitions are extremely similar, (as far as I can tell) the nuance is what the word is referencing. Wither generally refers to dying, whereas shrivel is less specific. With wither you could say "the leaves withered", but you couldn't refer to a wet towel 'withering'. However, shrivel is nonspecific, and you could thus refer to leaves  *or*  wet towels shriveling after a long day in the sun.

Answer (score 0):

All the dictionaries I just consulted define at least one of those words by way of the other or offer them as synonyms. All of them have definitions or usage examples for one or both of them that involve plants.